# Python code, Time delay on console text

Tags: python, time, console, delay

I'm making a code which should print text on console and every letter should came with a little delay. I've tried something like this

```
from time import sleep
print "H", sleep(0.1), "e", sleep(0.1), "l", sleep(0.1), "l", sleep(0.1), "o"
```

but it puts random "None" there. What should I do?
Help please  :?:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sleep` returns None, which gets printed. You could `print` each char without a newline and then sleep:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

for c in "Hello":
    print c,        # note the comma
    sleep(0.1)
print               # the final newline
```

but to avoid spaces inbetween, you'll have to do something like this:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

for c in "Hello":
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Depeding on your environment, you might need to also flush the stdout buffer:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

for c in "Hello":
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with separate prints:

```
from time import sleep

print "H",
sleep(0.1)
print "e",
sleep(0.1)
# ...
```

Note that using print like this will have some whitespace between characters.

The reason you see `None` printed is because `sleep` returns `None` and your script attempts to print what `sleep` returns.